# What is causing this cascade menu failure with tkinter in python?

Tags: python, menu, tkinter, cascade

The following code exhibits a problem I do not understand:

```python
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

cheese_var = IntVar()
parrot_var = IntVar(value=1)
check_menu = Menu(tearoff=0)
check_menu.add_checkbutton(label="Cheese", variable=cheese_var)
check_menu.add_checkbutton(label="Parrot", variable=parrot_var)
count = 0

class Top():
    def __init__(self):
        global count
        count += 1
        self.tl = Toplevel(root)
        Label(self.tl, text="Window " + str(count)).pack()
        self.mb = Menubutton(self.tl, text="Push Me", bg='pink')
        self.menu = Menu(self.mb, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="Choices", menu=check_menu)
        self.menu.add_command(label="New Window", command=new_top)
        self.mb.config(menu=self.menu)
        self.mb.pack()

def new_top():
    Top()

Top()
root.mainloop()
```

The menu brought up by the menu button in the created top level window initially behaves as expected.  Clicking on the New Window command there creates a new such window, which also behaves as expected.  Indeed, as long as you keep creating new top level windows, everything continues to work as expected.  However, once you delete (close) any one of those windows, then, in a subsequently created new window, the Choices cascade on the new menu is not functional.  (It is still OK in the windows created before the closing of one.)

The situation in which I initially encountered this symptom was much more complex, but I was able to simplify it down to the above example which exhibits the issue. I have discovered that I can avoid the problem by having each instance of Top create its own check_menu as an attribute; but I do not understand why this should be necessary.  Please point me the way if there is one to avoid the problem without such replication of a cascade menu used in multiple windows.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to do what you want.  I'll try to explain as best as I can.

When you first run the script, check_menu is created and works fine for the first window.  As you create more windows, check_menu is simply shared between them.  However, when you close one of them, check_menu (and everything under it) is destroyed.  So, when you create a new window after that, check_menu no longer exists and it doesn't show.

However, the script doesn't throw an error because, for some reason, Tkinter allows you to assign menus to things that aren't menus.  Believe it or not, none of the following code:

```
self.menu.add_cascade(label="Choices", menu=None)
self.menu.add_cascade(label="Choices", menu=1)
self.menu.add_cascade(label="Choices", menu="")
```

will break the script.  Each line simply does nothing but create an empty cascade "Choices".

That is basically what is happening.  After closing one window, check_menu and everything under it is destroyed.  Yet, Tkinter doesn't throw an error but instead assigns a menu to something that is no longer a menu (as far as what it is assigning the menu to, I believe it is using the old instance of check_menu, which was destroyed).

To solve this problem, recreate check_menu and everything under it each time you call Top.  In other words, put the code for check_menu (and its options) in the `__init__` method of Top.  That way, each time Top is called, check_menu will exist.

Hope this helps (and that I explained it sufficiently :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand that it does not work; but I remain unclear as to why, and I suspect that there must be a bit more to a complete explanation.  What I have come to expect is that, as long as there are references to an object, it will continue to exist.  If the menu has been destroyed as you say, how is it that it continues to function in the windows created prior to the destruction of one?  If I examine the value of check_menu after closing one of the windows, I get <Tkinter.Menu instance at 0x0000000004237F48>.